# wxPython-Unknown image data format(wxhtml)

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to load a Web page by wxhtml, and use the code to test.
from [enter link description here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0380__wxPython/LoadwebpagetoHtmlWindow.htm)

But I got a problem:  **Unknown image data format.**
[image: Image added]

```
import wx
import wx.html

class MyHtmlFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, size=(600,400))
        html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self)
        if "gtk2" in wx.PlatformInfo:
            html.SetStandardFonts()

        wx.CallAfter(html.LoadPage, "http://www.google.com")

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frm = MyHtmlFrame(None, "Simple HTML Browser")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: post the error as it is, show us the line number

Comment: When I run this pro, then I get a dialog about the error, I post the error picture on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted worked for me on Xubuntu 14.04 with wxPython 2.8.12.1 and Python 2.7. However, I would highly recommend that you use a different widget. The HtmlWindow is only supposed to be used for basic HTML, not for loading websites. For that, I would recommend using [webview](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html), which I believe was added in wxPython 2.9. It would work much better for this sort of thing.

Comment: thx, I ran it in windows 8 with wxPython 3.0 and Python27, about webview, the function New() in Class WebView, it calls the function WebView_New() in Class _html2, and I just find the file named _html2.pyd, a dll file in Windows. It means I can only use the IE to show my pages in Windows?

Comment: According to the docs: webview used Trident on MSW and Webkit on OSX and GTK -http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html